# How to speed up data readings from dataframe columns in python?

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, dataframe

[My data frame looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/plEoD.png)

Good day,

I'm trying to read values of every row from 4 different columns in my data frame and store it in a single NumPy array (See attached picture). Each column has 150.000 data rows and the single NumPy array results on having 600.000 rows of data. I have to do it 4 times which means I have to create 4 x 600.000 long arrays. I used a basic for-loop in my Python code but it took almost 5 minutes to compute.
Does anyone know a better way to do this in order to improve its performance?

Thank you,

Here is my Python Code:

```
    def oversampling(self):
    # Oversampling restructuring
    sh = self.df[['nSensor01_00']].values.shape
    nSensor01 = np.zeros(shape=(sh[0] * 4, 1))
    nSensor02 = np.zeros(shape=(sh[0] * 4, 1))
    nSensor03 = np.zeros(shape=(sh[0] * 4, 1))
    nSensor04 = np.zeros(shape=(sh[0] * 4, 1))
    temp = np.arange(4, sh[0] * 4, 4)
    ttime = np.arange(0, sh[0] / 500, 0.0005)
    names = ['nSensor01', 'nSensor02', 'nSensor03', 'nSensor04']
    for i in temp:
        ind_begin = i - 4
        ind_end = ind_begin + 4
        a = int((i - 1) / 4)
        nSensor01[ind_begin:ind_end ] = self.df.iloc[a, 55:59 ].values.flatten().reshape((4,1))
        nSensor02[ind_begin:ind_end ] = self.df.iloc[a, 59:63 ].values.flatten().reshape((4,1))
        nSensor03[ind_begin:ind_end ] = self.df.iloc[a, 63:67 ].values.flatten().reshape((4,1))
        nSensor04[ind_begin :ind_end ] = self.df.iloc[a, 67:71 ].values.flatten().reshape((4,1))

    d = np.hstack((nSensor01, nSensor02, nSensor03, nSensor04))
    self.dfkHz = pd.DataFrame(data=d, columns=names)
    self.dfkHz.insert(0, 'Time', ttime)
```

Comment: Could you provide a simpler, smaller example of the expected input and output, along with code that works on that input and generates the correct output? That way we can try it out and test the code.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
sh = self.df[['nSensor01_00']].values.shape
df_kHz = pd.DataFrame()
df_kHz["time"] = (np.arange(0, sh[0] / 500, 0.0005))
df_kHz["nSensor01"] = self.df.iloc[:, 55:59].values.flatten()
df_kHz["nSensor02"] = self.df.iloc[:, 59:63].values.flatten()
df_kHz["nSensor03"] = self.df.iloc[:, 63:67].values.flatten()
df_kHz["nSensor04"] = self.df.iloc[:, 67:71].values.flatten()
```

Comment: Hi apw-ub. It worked! Thank you... now it only takes 65 s to compute.